# Why would we need to use the #expr directive in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, preprocessor

Here's the documentation for [Inno Setup Preprocessor: #expr](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_expr.htm) and this one is for [Inno Setup Preprocessor: Preprocessor output](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_translation.htm).

Why would we want to use the `#expr` directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [`#expr` documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=expr) explicitly mentions, why would you use the directive:

> This directive is intended to be used with functions that produce side effects and do not return any significant value.

The documentation also shows a practical example of that:

```
#expr SaveToFile(...)
```

---

It seems that you do not know, what a *side effect* it. Check the Wikipedia article on [Side effect (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) (emphasis mine):

> **Function ... is said to have a side effect if** it modifies some state variable value(s) outside its local environment, that is to say **has an observable effect besides returning a value (the main effect) to the invoker of the operation**.

In the case of the [`SaveToFile` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=savetofile), the *side effect* is the saving of the function parameter to a file. This particular function does not even return anything. So it would be safe to use it with the [`#emit` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit):

```
#emit SaveToFile(...)
```

It would still save the file. And as the function "returns" `void`, it won't emit anything (though it actually emits an empty line, but that's in most cases ignored by Inno Setup). But it's confusing to use `#emit`, as a reader of the code might expect the function actually does return (and consequently emit) something. Use of the `#expr` explicitly shows that the expression (and whole directive) has no effect on the script contents.

---

And with expressions/functions that do return something, like with [`ForceDirectories`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=forcedirectories) or [`Exec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec), you have to use `#expr`. Of course, it makes sense only in case you do not bother checking the results.

```
#expr ForceDirectories(Path)
```

With `#emit`, the function would emit its result, what would result in an invalid script.

Another way to do, what `#expr` does, is using the `#emit` with a comma operator with `void` second parameter:

```
#emit ForceDirectories(Path), void
```

Though again, this emits an empty line. And it's less obvious, what you want to do, than with the `#expr`.